# Detect which button is pressed with an UIButton Array

Tags: ios, uibutton, iboutlet

I have an UIButton array like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btn_Impact_Collection;
```

and I have this function:

```
- (IBAction)impactAction:(id)sender;
```

In the XIB file I have nine button, each button is connected to btn_Impact_Collection Array with the Referencing Outlet Collection. Moreover the Touch_inside property of each button is connected to the function ImpactAction.

Now, when a button is clicked the ImpactAction function is called, but inside this function, how can i know which button is pressed?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cast sender to UIButton class, and that will give you the instance of the clicked button. I don't have Xcode with me but something like:

```
if ([sender isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    // Then you can reference the title or a tag of the clicked button to do some further conditional logic if you want.
    if([btn.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"title of button"])
    {
        // do something.
    }
    else if(etc...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
In my case i have to change the color of the button pressed. So it works simply with the following code:

 - (IBAction)impactAction:(id)sender{
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
     [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:     
 }

Comment: Not necessary to check if sender isKindOfClass since the selector is being linked via IB?

Comment: Or rather, isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]

Comment: That one line, indeed, should be changed to: 
    if ([sender isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

Answer (score 13):

Set tags for each button in interface builder (1-9), then say

```
if ([sender tag] == 1) {
//First button was pressed, react.
}
else if ([sender tag] == 2) {
//Second button was pressed, react.
}
// Etc...
else {
//Last button was pressed, react.
}
```

And the same for all the others, or you could put it in a switch.

Comment: Thank a lot, but in this way I am not able to know which button is pressed between all the buttons

Comment: @benza, in your case as I think you're using Interface Builder, you would need to set the tag value for each of your UIButton's for this to work. In any event, the sender variable is going to be the UIButton sending the action.

Comment: This doesn't scale well as you need to manually set all the tags in IB (what if you need to insert a new button at some point?). Also you generally want to avoid long nested if's where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than do a string check on the title (which is slow and can be tedious) you can:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    for( UIButton *button in self.buttonCollection )
    {
        if( sender == button )
        {
            // sender is your button (eg. you can access its tag)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, The other answers showed how to select a specific button, but not how to handle deselected buttons. thank you. +1

Answer (score 0):

Another option.. Cast sender to check if it's a UIButton, then switch sender.tag:

```
if ([sender isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        switch ([sender tag]) {
            case 0:
                //do stuff for button with tag 0
                break;

            case 1:
                //do stuff for button with tag 1
                break;

            case 2:
                ....
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```